# Ошибка в логах PHP #2

Tags: php

> PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in

Жалуется на `$code = func::cacheCheck('view'.$1.$2.$3, $array, $file);`

Comment: добавьте проверку на тип переменной  `is_array($array)`

Comment: $1, $2 или $3 является массивом

Comment: Массивом является $array

Comment: Эдуард, то есть $code = func::cacheCheck('view'.$1.$2.$3, is_array($array), $file); ?

Comment: $array на этом этапе имеет право являться вообще чем угодно, ошибка выстреливает на конкатенации `'view'.$1.$2.$3`, где одна из переменных является массивом.

Comment: *PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in* означает, что вы используете массив там, где должна быть строка. у вас тут конкатенация строк. там и ошибка

Comment: Представленный в вопросе фрагмент кода вообще не может быть PHP, т.к. обращение $1 синтаксически некорректно `syntax error, unexpected '1.' (T_DNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'`

Comment: @Webmaster, нет - над этим кодом, в котором используется $array, надо написать проверку, вида `$array = is_array($array) ? $array : [];` Ещё вам совет - чтобы ваши комментарии были видны их адресатам - ставьте значёк собачки сразу перед ником адресата.

Comment: @Эдуард не помогло, это я как понимаю как сказал splash58 передается массив $array там, где должна быть строка?

Comment: @splash58, что можно сделать в данном случае? У меня если убрать $array оттуда, то скрипт перестает работать.

Comment: @Webmaster распечатайте ваши переменные, которые в конкатенации строк, ну то что у вас $1... посмотрите их значения.

Comment: @Webmaster ну на самом деле в приведённом вами коде есть несколько несоответствий, вы сперва проверьте синтаксис, правильно ли вы переписали сюда код, т.к. проблема в не правильной записи переменных, а так же в использовании оператора конкатенации `.` для массивов.

Comment: @Webmaster добавьте больше код в вопрос, например код метода `cacheCheck`, откуда взялись **НЕкорректные** переменные `$1.$2.$3`, входные данные `$array` и `$file` и т.д. В текущем виде - гадание на кофейной гуще